# How to convert a text input from a string into a float

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a calculator/unit conversion app, and simply want text input to only accept floats and integers. I have tried making the text input keyboard a numberpad, but the program is still treating it as a "String?".

Edit: My end goal is to have a text input that accepts floats, and can allow my program to treat that as such. Currently, when a number is entered, the code still treats it as a string. I want it to be converted to a float.

I read that using `(...as NSString).floatValue` would work, but doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOutput: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberInput: UITextField!

    //

    @IBAction func onTouchDown(_ sender: UITextField) {
        var number = (numberInput.text as NSString).floatValue
        print(number*2)
    } 
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm relatively new to Swift, but from what I could figure out from that post, it is only for 2 digits for currencies. Ideally, I would like to have up to 3 or 4

Comment: @Addison Your question says nothing about what you _do_ want. Your only question seems to be that the text is a string, which is true and makes perfect sense. Edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: By the way, the keyboard is irrelevant. The user can still paste "Howdy!" into the text field. The keyboard has _nothing_ to do with how you guarantee that only numbers are accepted into a text field.

Comment: @matt just edited. Yeah thats another concern of mine. Any ideas on how to solve that as well? Again, the end goal is to have a text input that only accepts ints/floats, can successfully convert it to a float, and then preform mathematical operations on it

Comment: Right, you are asking two very different things. A text field's text _is_ a string ("text" field, get it?). That's just a fact. So the questions would be (1) how convert a string to a number and (2) how to guarantee that what the user enters into the text field _can_ be converted to a number. Which are you not clear about? You were pointed to a very good link that should help you.

Comment: @matt no need to apologize! I am unclear about how to guarantee that the user can only input numbers, and that the numbers can be converted to a float. I took a look at that link, and it didn't make a whole lot of sense. Ill take another look and do some more reading to try and figure it out. Let me know if you have a simpler solution though!

Comment: Check  this link [Limit input for Decimal Number](https://www.markusbodner.com/2017/06/20/how-to-verify-and-limit-decimal-number-inputs-in-ios-with-swift/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ilRn7VrL9M

This guy did it the simplest way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberINput: UITextField!
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let numberString = numberINput.text
    let number = NSString(string: numberString!).floatValue
    let finalValue = number*3
    resultsTxt.text = "\(finalValue)"
```

So I did end up having to use NSString, just not the original way I had learned/tried. Thanks to all of those that helped!

Comment: Try it when the `numberInput` text is "howdy". Does this give the result you want?

Comment: @matt yup! It simply returns 0 if the text input starts with a letter. If however it is something like '9k4h', it will return the first number (9) multiplied by 3 (which is in the code ^^). I am not concerned though with that. I mean it would be good if they simply couldn't paste in anything, but its fine. Also it will round 3 places automatically when calculating, which is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can allow only numbers and "." using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: Range, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
        {
            let newCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
            let isNumber = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: newCharacters)
            if isNumber {
                return true
            } else {
                if string == "." {
                    let dotscount = textField.text!.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1
                    if dotscount == 0 {
                        return true
                    } else {
                        if dotscount > 0 && string == "." {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
```

Don't forget about set `textField.delegate = self` (in your case is `numberInput.delegate = self`) in `viewDidLoad()` and add `UITextFieldDelegate` as protocol of your viewController class (your case is `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`)

This method will replace all the characters, except (1234567890 and one ".")

You can get numberInput.text as Int or Float just like that `Int(numberInput.text)!` or `Float(numberInput.text)!`

Answer (score -1):

Might be issue with optional type,
numberInput.text will return an optional value.

try to use bellow code
let number = (numberInput.text as NSString?)?.floatValue
print(number!*2)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
import UIKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController{ 
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOutput: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberInput: UITextField! 

    // 

    @IBAction func onTouchDown(_ sender: UITextField) { 
        var number: Float = Float(numberInput.text)
        print(number*2)  
    }
}
```

It might give you warnings about optional values, but it should say "Fix". Just press that and it will fix the warning.